# Can you help to solve problem with the jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

[image]

please find the below image can any one help me solve

Comment: The executable 'mvnw' is not found in that specific location.

Answer (score 0):

This command is unable to locate the executable 'mvnw' in the current directory, either the file is missing or located in a different path. Please try giving the full path of the file.